# Adding columns and manipulating existing column values in csv file using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, batch-processing

I have a lot of csv files with values arranged like so:

```
X1,Y1
X2,Y2
...,...
Xn,Yn
```

I find it very tedious processing these with excel, so I want to setup a batch script to process these files such that they appear like this:

```
#where N is a specified value like 65536
X1,N-Y1,1
X2,N-Y2,2
...,...,...
Xn,N-Yn,n
```

I have only recently started using powershell for image processing (really simple scripts) and file name appending, so I am not certain how to go about this. A lot of the scripts I have encountered looking to answer this question use csv files with titles per column whereas my files are just arrays of values without object titles in the first row. I would like to avoid running multiple scripts to add titles.

My bonus question is something I have yet to find a good answer to at all, and is the most tedious part of processing. Using excels sort function, I usually change the order of the Yn values in Col2 such that they are sorted in the exported csv like so:

```
X1,N-Yn,n
...,...,...
Xn-1,N-Y2,2
Xn,N-Y1,1
```

Using the Col3 values as the sorting order (largest to smallest), then I delete this column so that the final saved csv only contains the first two columns (crucial step). Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, I apologize for the long-winded-ness of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have encountered looking to answer this question use csv files with titles per column whereas my files are just arrays of values without object titles in the first row.

The `-Header` parameter of `Import-Csv` is for adding column headers when the file does not contain them. It takes an array of strings, of however many columns there are.

> I would like to avoid running multiple scripts to add titles.

If you couldn't use `-Header`, you could read the lines with `Get-Content` into memory, add a header in memory, and then use `ConvertFrom-CSV` all in one script.

That said, if I'm reading it rightly, you want:

- No headers in the input file, and I imagine no headers in the output file
- The whole point of adding the third column and sorting and removing it is just to reverse the lines?
- The only column you keep is column 1?

I wouldn't use Import-Csv for this, it won't make it much nicer.

```
$n = 65536

# Read lines into a list, and reverse it
$lines = [Collections.Generic.List[String]](Get-Content -LiteralPath 'c:\test\test.csv')
$lines.Reverse()


# Split each line into two, create a new line with X and N-Y
# write new lines to an output file
$lines | ForEach-Object {

    $x, $y = $_.split(',')

    "$x,$($n - [int]$y)"

} | Set-Content -LiteralPath 'c:\test\output.csv' -Encoding Ascii
```

If you do want to use CSV handling, then:

```
$n = 65536
$counter = 1
Import-Csv -LiteralPath 'C:\test\test.csv' -Header 'ColX', 'ColY' |
    Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name 'ColN-Y' -Value {$n - $_.ColY} -PassThru |
    Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name 'N' -Value {$script:counter++} -PassThru |
    Sort-Object -Property 'N' -Descending |
    Select-Object -Property 'ColX', 'ColN-Y' |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath 'c:\test\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

But the output will have CSV headers and double-quoted values.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I do not want headers in the output csv files if it can be avoided. Both scripts worked on individual csv files, what I am wondering is how to pipeline either script to process all files in a directory as I have lots csv's. I've tried including Get-ChildItem command but the exported csv only contained a list of the file names and did not process them.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like, by extending the original table with a calculatable script-property as a new column:

```
#Your N number
$N = 65536

# Import CSV file without header columns
$table = Import-Csv -Header @("colX","colY") `
    -Delimiter ',' `
    -Path './numbers.csv'

Write-Host "Original table"
$table | Format-Table

# Manipulate table
$newtable = $table |
Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name colNX -Value { $N-$this.colX } - PassThru

Write-Host "New table"
$newtable | Format-Table
```